# Lifting operator on rank-one $uv^T$ matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

Suppose I have the following rank-one matrix $$uv^T=\begin{bmatrix} u_1\\u_2\\u_3 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} v_1 & v_2 & v_3 \end{bmatrix}$$

Suppose I have the following lifting operator $\mathcal{A}: \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}\rightarrow \mathcal{S}^{4\times 4}$ $$\mathcal{A}(Y)=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
Y_{11}-Y_{22}-Y_{33} & Y_{12}+Y_{21} & Y_{13}+Y_{31} & Y_{23}-Y_{32} \\
Y_{12}+Y_{21} & -Y_{11}+Y_{22}-Y_{33} & Y_{23}+Y_{32} & -Y_{13}+Y_{31} \\
Y_{13}+Y_{31} & Y_{23}+Y_{32} & -Y_{11}-Y_{22}+Y_{33} & Y_{12}-Y_{21} \\
Y_{23}-Y_{32} & -Y_{13}+Y_{31} & Y_{12}-Y_{21} & Y_{11}+Y_{22}+Y_{33}
\end{array}\right]$$

Can we say something about the rank and column space of $\mathcal{A}(uv^T)$?  For example, the rank of $\mathcal{A}(uv^T)$ is one.

I believe so far it is obvious that

1. it is symmetric
2. trace$(\mathcal{A}(Y))=0$

Thanks!

Comment: The best hope would seem to be to present $\mathcal{A}$ in some more familiar matter, e.g., as $\mathcal{A}(Y)=BYC$ for appropriate rectangular matrices $B,C$. But it's not obvious that that's possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\def\R{{\mathbb R}}\def\m#1{ \left[\begin{array}{c}#1\end{array}\right] }$Let
$\epsilon\in\R^{3\times 3\times 3}$ denote the [Levi-Civita symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol) and
$I\in\R^{3\times 3}$ denote the identity matrix. Use these to define the following scalar, vector, matrix functions of the $Y$ matrix
$$\eqalign{
\alpha &= {\rm trace}(Y) \;=\; I:Y \\
a &= \epsilon:Y \\
A &= Y + Y^T - \alpha I \;=\; A^T\\
}$$
where $(:)$ denotes the double-contraction product.

The following constants will also be useful
$$\eqalign{
z &= \m{0\\0\\0} \qquad
E &= \m{I\\z^T} \qquad
e &= \m{0\\0\\0\\1} \\
}$$
Then your *lifting operator* can be expressed in a form which lends itself to algebraic manipulation
$$\eqalign{
{\cal A}(Y) 
 &= \m{A&a\\a^T&\alpha} 
 \;\doteq\; EAE^T + Eae^T + ea^TE + \alpha ee^T \\
}$$
Setting $Y=uv^T$ yields
$$\eqalign{
\alpha &= u^Tv \qquad
a &= u\times v \qquad
A &= uv^T + vu^T - (u^Tv)I \\
}$$
where $(\times)$ denotes the vector cross product.